# tf.keras model saving discrepancy

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I noticed a discrepancy between the two savings function available in `tf.keras` that both seem to do the same thing and I wonder what the actual difference is.

When I save a model using the following method and then evaluate its size by:

```py
model.save(path)


print("Size of the model: %.2f Mb" % (os.path.getsize(path) / float(2**20)))
```

I have:

> Size of the model: 172.13 Mb

But if now I try with the function:

```py
tf.keras.models.save_model(model, path)
```

I have:

> Size of the model: 57.39 Mb

By looking at the documentation of both Keras and `tf.keras` I found:

*`tf.keras.models.save_model`: The saved model contains: - the model's configuration (topology) - the model's weights - the model's optimizer's state (if any)*

And:

*`model.save()`:  to save a Keras model which will contain:the architecture of the model,the weights of the model, the training configuration (loss, optimizer), the state of the optimizer.*

Both seem to achieve the same thing so my guess is that `tf.keras.save_model` probably do some operation in the background (compression ?). Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The GitHub source code of [model.save](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py#L1120) and [tf.keras.models.save_model](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py#L47) ultimately lead to the internal method of [save](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save.py#L61) present in tensorflow.python.keras.saving.saved_model package if your save format is 'tf' or it leads to internal method of [save_model_to_hdf5](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py#L46) if your save format is 'h5'. You maybe doing something wrong in your approach.